# Sonata Admin Change Edit link by Show link

Tags: symfony, routes, hyperlink, configure, sonata-admin

I'm using SonataAdminBundle and I'm triying to change the edit link of and entity by the show link.

I want to do this because I need the entity couldn't be modified but I want you can show the entity by clicking in the Identifier field of the list page.

I need to show the entity by clicking in the Identifier, and not using the show action buttom.

So I tried in the ClassAdmin:

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection){

  $collection->add('edit',  $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/show');

}
```

Despite the url is generated with the show correctly, the Identifier in the list page redirect to the edit page. Really, wathever I change in the edit link doesn't take efect and always redirect to the edit page.

Thansk a lot!

Comment: have you cleared your cache?

Comment: if you really don't need the edit view then just extend the edit view and redirect on that page to the show view? I know it's dirty, but maybe it works.

Comment: Extend the edit views is too dirty hahaha but in the last moment it could be an option, unless I don't like so much :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Finally, it works by:

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection){

    $collection->remove('edit');
    $collection->add('edit',  $this->getRouterIdParameter().'/show');

}
```

I don't know why I have to remove the edit link first... but it works.

Comment: I think that the @shinework answer is better in most of cases.

Answer (score 25):

You can give the default action like this (in your admin classes):

```
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('id', null, ['route' => ['name' => 'show']])
    ;
}
```